# Cannot read properties of null (reading '_rawValidators') error on using Ngmodel on custom components

Tags: angular

1. Iam using a control value accessor for my custom components,its
   working properly for
   formcontrol, when I use ngModel its shows an error and my Writevalue method didn't called,its shows error on console, for adding both formcontrol and ngModel its working , for using
   ngModel alone its shows error

my parent component looks like this

```
  <div class="">
    <h3  class="text-primary">lable list</h3>
    <app-table-list-dropdown [items]="listStatus" (onValueChange)="onStatusChange($event)"
    [(ngModel)]="values" name="custom-list"></app-table-list-dropdown>
 </div>


child component html--

    <div class="dropdown-table-container">
       <ng-select [items]="items" [clearable]="false" [(ngModel)]="input" 
         [searchable]="searchable"
        class="dropdown-select" (ngModelChange)="onchange($event)"
        [disabled]="disable">
      </ng-select>
    </div>


child component ts file

     import { Component, EventEmitter, forwardRef, Input, OnInit, Output } from 
     '@angular/core';
     import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

     @Component({
     selector: 'app-table-list-dropdown',
     templateUrl: './table-list-dropdown.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./table-list-dropdown.component.scss'],
     providers: [
       {
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        multi: true,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => TableListDropdownComponent)
       }
     ]
    })
      export class TableListDropdownComponent implements  OnInit,ControlValueAccessor {

     // @Input() formControl:any;
     // @Input() ngModel:any;
     @Input() items:any
     @Input() searchable:boolean = false;
     @Input() disable:boolean = false;
     @Output() onValueChange = new EventEmitter<Event>();
     input:any;

     constructor() { }

     ngOnInit(): void {
     // this.input = this.ngModel;
     }

    onChange = (data:any) => {}
     onTouch = (_:any) => {}

     registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
      this.onChange = fn;
     }

     registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
      this.onTouch = fn;
     }

     writeValue(value: string) {
      this.input = value;
      this.onChange(value);
     }

     onchange(event:any){
      this.onChange(event);
      this.onValueChange.emit(event);
      }

    }

i am not why its shows error..

src_app__modules_property-manager_property-manager_module_ts.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read 
 properties of null (reading '_rawValidators')
    at xe (forms.mjs:901:20)
    at Le (forms.mjs:3065:24)
    at te (forms.mjs:2989:5)
    at no.addControl (forms.mjs:4853:9)
    at er._setUpControl (forms.mjs:4091:77)
    at er.ngOnChanges (forms.mjs:4050:18)
    at er.Bo (core.mjs:1526:14)
    at kn (core.mjs:2508:18)
    at en (core.mjs:2467:17)
    at Qn (core.mjs:2418:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined control and that control has validators. When control is UNDEFINED than your code is trying to do validation on non existing control. When using ControlValueAccessor it work with CONTROLS as part of **Form** controls.

documentation: https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

quote:

> Defines an interface that acts as a bridge between the Angular **forms API** and a native element in the DOM.

Please check if you have you FormControl inside FormGroup and Form is defined in html file. Like so:

```
<form [formGroup]='form'>
```

Please try NOT to use [FormControl] but FormControlName="control name here". Please see documentation : https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName.

If formControlName directive will be added to PARENT component tag then writeValue will trigger for sure.

Please DO NOT use FormControl and ngModel together. it is not good for you. Please see articles:

1. https://dev.to/jwp/angular-10-ngmodel-and-formcontrols-e0g
2. https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel-is-deprecated

I think that would help:

```
<app-table-list-dropdown [items]="listStatus" (onValueChange)="onStatusChange($event)"
FormControlName="values" name="custom-list"></app-table-list-dropdown>

//values should be control name defined in controler 
// like so: 
// in example 
// const control = new FormControl('values', []);
```

you may also delare all controls like so:

```
  form = new FormGroup({
values: new FormControl(''),
someOtherControl: new FormControl(''),
```

});

if changed in child by ngModel event emiter will send change up and trigger onStatusChange function like so:

```
   onStatusChange(newValue) {
          this.form.controls.values.setValue(newValue)
// "form" you should replace with your form name declared in formGroup
    }
```

Comment: I used the child component inside the <form [FormGroup]="sampleForm">,most of the control value accessor tutorial shows using ngmodel works, but for mine it did'nt

Comment: ngModel is ok but not mixed with FormControl. So newer do <myComponnent FormControlName="myControl" [ngModel]="value"> </myComponnent>. ngModel used alone for passing inside controlValueAccesor template/view is OK.

Comment: For ControlValueAccessors use event to pass value up. Like you did with this.onValueChange.emit(event); and (onValueChange)="onStatusChange($event)". For passing value INSIDE child it is ok like you did  [(ngModel)]="input" but Parent element must be tagged with FormControlName and NOT having ngModel . onValueChange should do changes inside parent.

Comment: You must understand that ngModel and FormControl are similar but have different properties. ForControl gives you more possibilities. Both does steer and holds VALUE passed to child . FormControl though, holds validators which is bonus in comparison with ngModel.

Comment: yes For using ngModel alone only, it shows an error and I don't know why

Comment: Inside child ngModel or parent. I assume parent right ?

Comment: You try to use ControlValueAccessor and it works for CONTROLS not ngModel.